# Automatically update a widget

Tags: widget

can someone help me add a code so this widget automatically update every 60 seconds without the page being refreshed?

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
<div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
<div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a 
href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"> 
<span class="blue-text">Technical Analysis for EURUSD</span></a> by TradingView</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed- 
widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
{
"interval": "1m",
"width": 425,
"isTransparent": false,
"height": 450,
"symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
"showIntervalTabs": true,
"locale": "en",
"colorTheme": "dark"
}
</script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```